# WinSock2 sockaddr structure as a parameter

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, winsock2

What is the point of having functions such as inet_ntop, WSAAddressToString, recvfrom also require either the size of the actual sockaddr structure or the address family to be provided?

The first two bytes of the sockaddr structure indicate the address family and therefore also indicate whether it's actually sockaddr_in or sockaddr_in6.

So what is the reason for the additional sizeof(sockaddr_in/sockaddr_in6) and AF_INET/AF_INET6?

Answer (score 0):

`sockaddr` is a legacy type.  There are newer `sockaddr_...` types for specific address families, like `sockaddr_in` for IPv4 and `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6, and they have different byte sizes.  APIs operate on generic `sockaddr*` pointers partly for historic reasons and partly for flexibility.  Socket APIs recognize multiple address types.  You usually have to provide sizes so the APIs can validate your memory buffers are large enough to pass address data based on the specified families (`AF_INET` for IPv4, `AF_INET6` for IPv6).

In `inet_ntop()`, `in_addr` and `in6_addr` do not contain an address family, that is why you have to pass it separately.  You are responsible for making sure you specify the correct address family for the input type you are passing in.

In `WSAAddressToString()`, the `sockaddr*` pointer to an input buffer.  You have to pass the allocated size of that buffer.  For instance, since `sockaddr_in` is smaller than `sockaddr_in6`, if you allocate a `sockaddr_in` but set its family to `AF_INET6` instead of `AF_INET`, the buffer is too small for the function to access all of the IPv6 fields, so it will fail with an `WSAEFAULT` error instead of crashing.

In `recvfrom()`, the `sockaddr*` is a pointer to an output buffer.  You have to preallocate it and pass the allocated size.  If you allocate a `sockaddr_in` but receive an IPv6 packet, the sender's address will not fit in your buffer and the function will fail with an `WSAEFAULT` error.